# Nginx server blocks PDF index

Tags: nginx, centos-7

I have set the following server block

```
server
 {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  rm.madsfi.pw;
    root           /var/www/rm.madsfi.pw;
    index          port.pdf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/rm.madsfi.pw/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rm.madsfi.pw/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = rm.madsfi.pw) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  rm.madsfi.pw;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Why am I getting a forbidden error?

Folder perms:

```
drwxr-sr-x nginx nginx rm.madsfi.pw
```

Comment: What are the corresponding entries in the access log and error log?

Comment: 2019/08/06 10:42:25 [error] 27749#0: *3 open() "/var/www/rm.madsfi.pw/port.pdf" failed (13: Permission denied), client: $ip address$, server: rm.madsfi.pw, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "rm.madsfi.pw"

Comment: The permissions set are:

sudo chown nginx:nginx port.pdf
rm.madsfi.pw]$ sudo chmod 755 port.pdf